# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL Server from App Engine in the same project - Login timeout

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy

I am using the sample code that google has provided on github:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/sql-server/sqlalchemy

I have created a Cloud SQL server on the project and when I run the main.py file from my local machine, the database gets updated OK.
However, when I deploy the same code on Google App Engine, I get the following timeout error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 271, in handle keepalive = self.handle_request(req, conn) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 320, in handle_request respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in
__call__ return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise raise value File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1945, in full_dispatch_request self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1993, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions func() File "/app/main.py", line 116, in create_tables if not db.has_table("votes"): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2331, in has_table return self.run_callable(self.dialect.has_table, table_name, schema) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2211, in run_callable with self._contextual_connect() as conn: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2302, in _contextual_connect self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None), File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2339, in _wrap_pool_connect Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1583, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection util.raise_( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_ raise exception File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2336, in _wrap_pool_connect return fn() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 364, in connect return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 778, in _checkout fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 495, in checkout rec = pool._do_get() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 140, in _do_get self._dec_overflow() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__ compat.raise_( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_ raise exception File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 137, in _do_get return self._create_connection() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 309, in _create_connection return _ConnectionRecord(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 440, in __init__ self.__connect(first_connect_check=True) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__ compat.raise_( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_ raise exception File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect connection = pool._invoke_creator(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 493, in connect return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams) sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: Are you using App Engine Flex or Standard?

Comment: I am using the flex engine

Answer (score 0):

You need to [configure your App Engine Flex service to connect to a Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-flexible).

In your `app.yaml` you need to set:

```
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:PORT
```

Where the `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` has the following structure: `<project-name>:<region-name>:<instance-name>`

And when you connect, you should connect to `172.17.0.1:PORT` where `PORT` is the port you specified in the `app.yaml` file